# Baire space has isolated point

Tags: baire-category, the-baire-space

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff, Baire space. I want to prove that $X$ has an isolated point.

 In a Hausdorff space, singletons $\{x\}$ are closed.

 Now suppose for a contradiction $X$ has no isolated points. Then the set $X \setminus \{x\}$ is not open. How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it, since it is false. For instance, $\mathbb R$, endowed with the usual topology, is a Baire space, but it has no isolated point.

Comment: What if instead $X$ is countable?

Comment: Then it's quite easy to prove that it has isolated points.

Comment: I am still not sure how, though.

Comment: @wwinters57 Just write your countable space as union of singletons and apply definition of Baire space.

Comment: If $x$ is a non-isolated point, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is dense. And it is open, of course. But then, if there were no isolated points, the fact that $\bigcap_{x\in X}(X\setminus\{x\})=\emptyset$ would show that there would be a countable family of open and dense subsets of $X$ with empty intersection.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it now.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.